# How do you extract a specific TypeScript prop type from a React component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm creating my own Image component and want to reuse React's image component `ImageSourcePropType` for my source/previewSource props.

Here's the component.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Image, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';

type ImageSourceProp = React.ComponentProps<typeof Image>.ImageSourcePropType; // HOW?

interface CachedImageProps {
  source: ImageSourceProp;
  previewSource: ImageSourceProp;
}

const CachedImage: React.FC<CachedImageProps> = ({ source, previewSource, ...remainingProps }) => {
  // console.log('TRIGGERED CachedImage')

  return (
    <ImageBackground source={previewSource|| source} fadeDuration={0} {...remainingProps}>
      <Image source={cachedSource} fadeDuration={0} {...remainingProps} />
    </ImageBackground>
  );
};

export default CachedImage;
```

How do I get the `ImageSourcePropType`?

Comment: Why not just import the type from `'react-native'`? The type is exported from the module, so you can add it to your list of imports easily: `import { Image, ImageBackground, ImageSourcePropType } from 'react-native';`

Comment: Ha! I didn't realize that. Also found another way after posting the question yesterday.  I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, figured this one out. 
There are two ways to do it.

1. Access via name.

   ```
   type ImageSourcePropType = React.ComponentProps<typeof Image>['source'];
   ```
2. Access via `import`.

   ```
   import { ImageSourcePropType } from 'react-native';
   ```

   <sub>(hat tip @kschaer)</sub>

Comment: Yep! you can also roll your own type. `type PropsOf<C> = C extends (props: infer P) => any ? P : never`